# Referencing SVG as <img> in html breaks all <image> bitmaps in the SVG in most browsers

Tags: html, image, svg, xlink

Whenever I try to use an svg as an image in html using the  tag, any images referenced within the svg file using `<image xlink:href="">` tag won't display.

This fails to display any bitmaps at all in the svg in browsers (firefox, chome, chromium, safari) but does display the image in internet explorer).

**HTML FIle**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img src="svg.svg" height="100" width="200" />
</body>
</html>
```

**SVG File**

```
 <svg version="1.1"
    baseProfile="full"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" height="100" width="200">
    <image height="100" width="200" xlink:href="image1.jpg" />
    </svg>
```

**However if I place the exact same code directly in the html file as**

```
<svg height="100" width="200"> 
<image height="100" width="200" xlink:href="image1.jpg" />
</svg>
```

It works.

Or if I reference the same svg file with `<object data="">`  it also works.
Any vector objects (eg. rects) in the svg file also work fine with `<img>` or `<object>`.

If I load the svg file directly it works properly in all browsers.

Why is the img tag in html breaking my image tag xlinks in the svg file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any SVG that is been embedded using `<img>` cannot reference external objects (like other images).  This is a deliberate feature implemented by browsers for privacy reasons.

You can embed your SVG using `<object>` instead.  Alternatively, if you really need to use `<img>`, change your external image references in the SVG to Data URIs.

Comment: Ok thanks, I put the svg code directly in the html file instead of an svg file and it seems to display the <image>'s in firefox, ie, chromium but not safari. :(    So I assume I can't use that approach either.